# Serialize with PK and deserialize with field data in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following two serializers for the models `Person` and `Title` in my application,

```
class TitleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      class Meta:                                  
          model = Title                            
          exclude = ['created', 'modified']

class PatientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):                       
      title = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Title.objects.all())           

      class Meta:                                                                        
          model = Patient                                                          
          exclude = ['created', 'modified', 'owner']
```

My requirement is, I should be able to do a successful, POST with a `Person` payload and with the Primary Key for `Title`. For example,

```
{
    "title": 5,
    "name": "Sample Name",
    "age": "18"
}
```

Here 5 (for title) is the Primary Key of `Title`.

But when I do a GET, I need to get the actual data for title, for example,

```
{
    "title": "Mr.",
    "name": "Sample Name",
    "age": "18"
}
```

Is this requirement possible to achieve, if so what would be the best approach to follow?

Comment: You could just override `to_represetnation()` method to show the actual data for `GET` requests.

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Comment: No worries man :)